# Can i use Xbox 360's kinect sensor in Xbox one

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, kinect

In India, the kinect sensor of Xbox one is almost equal to the price of a brand new Xbox 360. I don't plan to spend money in which one can buy a whole new Xbox 360. So can i use Xbox 360's kinect sensor in Xbox one

Comment: No; the sensor is completely different; you wouldn't even be able to connect it for that reason alone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You can not share a Kinect sensor for Xbox 360 with an Xbox One. As @Ramhound points out, the two  iterations of the Kinect sensor do not even use the same connection.

Comment: To be fair both required a special adapter but you could get a cable adapter that split the data and power connectors  so legacy models of the Xbox 360 could also use it

Comment: @Ramhound, I remember plugging my Kinect v1 into my PC without an adapter, but I'll double check when I get home.

Comment: The PC version of Kinect didn't require an adapter, the adapter was only require for hardware that didn't have the USB//Data connector which meant it require a external power supply to function